# What regular expression can I use to match an IP address?

Tags: regex, grep, ip-address

With the following `grep` syntax I want to match all IP address in a file (from a `ksh` script)

```
  grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' file
```

The problem: It also matches words (IP) that have more then 4 octets:

```
1.1.1.1.1
```

or

```
192.1.1.1.160
```

How can I match a *valid* IP and only IP addresses with 4 octets? I can also use Perl – a one line syntax solution, if `grep` doesn't work.

Comment: It will match `999.999.999.999` too.

Comment: So, you only want to grep IPv4 addresses, [right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)?

Comment: And as for you `192.1.1.1.160` example: would you expect `192.1.1.1` or `1.1.1.160` or no match at all?

Comment: about 192.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.160 they valid IP I accept

Comment: Errr? So, if the input is `192.1.1.1.160` then you just want `192.1.1.1` in the output? Then you don't have a problem (except for [matching 999.999.999.999](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) an so on too), but just need the `-o` command line option to only print the actual matches, not the full lines?

Comment: Technically, IP addresses such as `192.1.4097` are valid and accepted by Linux glibc and Windows.

Comment: Ah, [I never knew](http://www.allredroster.com/iptodec.htm)! `ping 2130706433`, on OS X: `PING 2130706433 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes`.

Comment: @Arjan: `0x7f.1` and `0177.1`

Comment: Have a look at my answer in unix stackexchange:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389565/249079

Answer (score 62, accepted):

try this:

```
grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' /etc/hosts
```

which matches all expressions from `0.0.0.0` to `999.999.999.999`

with

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' /etc/hosts
```

you will get IP addresses only

**note:**
on solaris probably **egrep** will do the job.

Comment: I try the grep '\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b' /etc/hosts but I dont get anything -:(

Comment: @jennifer, you'll need to enable extended regular expressions: `grep -E <pattern> <file>` (or, to just print the matches: `grep -Eo <pattern> <file>`

Comment: like this ?  grep -E '\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b' /etc/hosts

Comment: I updated my answer -> this should work now

Comment: the problem is that -E isnt valid flag in solaris? -:(

Comment: add a "solaris" tag to your question. not sure how to tweak this on solaris...

Comment: try egrep on solaris ;) not sure if it works, but it should. let me know

Comment: @jennifer, that's info that should have been in your question... In the end, the trick is the `-o`, like I already commented earlier. The regex above is not different from the one in your question, but without the `-o` all matching *lines* are printed, even if only *part* of that line is matched. (To use the regex from this answer without the `-E` you'll just need `\{1,3\}` instead of `{1,3}`.)

Comment: @udo: Well this matches `1.1.1.1.1` but it hides the last `.1` from the output, I can't see how it can help.

Comment: Your regexp doesn't match 10.0.0.1

Comment: In my head this would be confusing to write but your answer is actually really easy to understand now that I see the syntax of the regex

Answer (score 11):

How's this:

```
perl -MRegexp::Common=net -ne '/($RE{net}{IPv4})/ and print "$1\n"' /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Nice! (This also returns `192.1.1.1.160` as `192.1.1.1`, which I think is fine for the question asker.)

Comment: If conformant IP addresses are really wanted, this is the only type of solution that has any chance of being close to complete. When I saw the question, I just thought "I won't touch that with a ten-foot standard regexp pole". Caveats, caveats everywhere :-) .

Answer (score 5):

The

```
-w / --word-regexp
```

flag to `grep` makes it only match on word boundaries, meaning that your match must either be surrounded by whitespace or begin / end at the beginning / end of the line!

Answer (score 5):

```
if [ ` echo $ip | '^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[1-9][0-9]?)$'  | grep -o "\." | wc -l` -eq 1 ];
then ipv4=true;
else 
ipv4=false;
```

Answer (score 5):

To only find matches with 4 octets exactly (excluding things like 1.1.1.1.1) use this:

```
grep -P '(?<=[^0-9.]|^)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.([0-9]{0,3})){3}(?=[^0-9.]|$)'
```

It should never detect non-IP-addresses. The expression could be more complex to verify more things but this should work for most cases. It will not match a preceding 0 since 010.1.12.1 is not a common way to write IP addresses.

Answer (score 3):

A little tricky, but it should work:

```
( X='\([0-9]\{1,2\}\|1[0-9]\{2\}\|2[0-4][0-9]\|25[0-5]\)' ; grep "\([^\.]\|^\)$X\.$X\.$X\.$X\([^\.]\|$\)" file )
```

Comment: What about `127.000.000.001` then? ;-)

Comment: As far as I know IPs doesn't have padding zeros.

Comment: Hmmm, `ping 127.000.000.001` surely works on my Mac. But then: I just learned that even `ping 2130706433` yields the very same result. :-) Oops, `ping 00127.00000.00000.00001` translates to `87.0.0.1`. Odd... Or octal maybe? Yes, octal for sure, so you're right about leading zeroes I guess.

Comment: Yes, 00127 (octal) = 87 (decimal). Surely they're all valid IPs, but I guess that's not the standard way to represent them. Anyway that's not requested by the asker.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version of the long regex:

```
egrep '([1-2]?[0-9]{0,2}\.){3,3}[1-2]?[0-9]{0,2}'
```

Please use grep -E or egrep as suitable to your OS version

Comment: welcome at superuser. This question already has several good answers. To help people understanding differences between them, please edit your answer and explain what makes it better / different from the other ones.

Comment: this expression does not take into account such legal ips as 8.8.8.8 `echo "8.8.8.8" | grep -Eo '([1-2][0-9]{0,2}\.){3,3}[1-2][0-9]{0,2}'` => no result

Answer (score 0):

> grep -E '^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[1]?[1-9][0-9]?).){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[1]?[1-9]?[0-9])$'

Modified version of Arnaud B.'s answer.

This expression will not match IP addresses with leading 0s. e.g., it won't match 192.168.1.01
This expression will not match IP addresses with more than 4 octets. e.g., it won't match 192.168.1.2.3

Comment: This won't match 127.0.0.1 either.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression for matching an ip address in TCL

> set a "192.168.10.25"
>
> ```
> if {[regexp
> {^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$} $a]} 
> {
>     puts "yes"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `egrep "^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" /etc/hosts`
 to match IP adresses at the beginning of a line.
It can also be used without the `^` to allow white spaces or other chars before the IP address.

```
[0-9]{1,3} --> this matches a number between 1 and 999.
\. --> this is to add the dot.
([0-9]{1,3}\.){3} --> get a number with a dot 3 times.
[0-9]{1,3} --> finally add the fourth number.
```

Answer (score 0):

grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}.?){4}'

Example :
curl http://korben.info/ip | grep "IP visible depuis mon serveur" | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}.?){4}'

Answer (score 0):

Old chain, but I needed a grep which would **ALSO CATCH CIDR masks (8-32)**, so I use this:

```
grep -Eo "\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]\
|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\
([/]([8-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-2]))?\b"
```

The above can be improved ;)

Now if mask is other than 8-32 but if the "IP-part" is still valid, grep returns the "IP-part".

Answer (score -1):

Here is what worked for me for ksh and ksh93 in AIX:

## ip=

[[ $ip == [0-9]@(""|[0-9])@(""|[0-9]).[0-9]@(""|[0-9])@(""|[0-9]).[0-9]@(""|[0-9])@(""|[0-9]).[0-9]@(""|[0-9])@(""|[0-9]) ]] && echo OK || echo NOK
The above can be modified in order to "filter" the provided IP to whatever pattern is desired.